# Nested form_for in _form.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to understand why for a typical nested resource, why we need to do this

`<%= form_for [@project,@ticket] do |f| %>`

instead of say:

`<%= form_for [@project,@project.ticket] do |f| %>` which doesn't work, or so on.

Would truly appreciate an explainer on `[@project, @ticket]` part as I understand it for singular controller, but not nested.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    root "projects#index"

    resources :projects do 
        resources :tickets 
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why must be used this way but, if you are more comfortable, you can use something like:

```
<%= form_for @project do |p| %>
  ...
  <%= fields_for :ticket, @project.ticket do |t| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

You can take a look to the [FormHelper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). It gives examples for every possible association.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you for answering. Sorry, that I wasn't clear in my question. I am trying to understand how this part `[@project,@ticket]` works for nested `_form.html.erb`

Comment: also, I just noticed in your example, you're using singular `@project` ... which I understand in `_form.html.erb`

Comment: my problem is with nested resources stuff which I always have trouble figuring out which is why I'm trying to break it apart and understand why this `[@project,@ticket]` is needed ... as opposed to say `[@project,@project..ticket]` which does not work.